# Windbg get time exception occurred

Tags: .net, windbg

I know that the command !dumpheap -type Exception will show all exceptions as shown below

```
.foreach (ex {!dumpheap -type Exception -short}){.echo "********";!pe ${ex} }
```

However in the application I'm currently trying to debug it looks as if a cascade effect has taken place where one exception has triggered 29 others across multiple threads. Is there any way of determining which was the first exception to occur ?

Comment: I *believe* that the order of objects in the heap matches their allocation order (since allocation always happens at the free end, and I understand compaction just shifts everything to lower addresses), but I don't think it's guaranteed.

Comment: More specifically it will show instances of all types with the word Exception in their names. The command itself is unaware of actual exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always faced this confusion. 
But in all cases the exception with higher memory address was the last one to occur.

Hence the exception with lowest memory address out of all those 29 exceptions is the first one to occur

[image: See the sample shown below]